# Issue with click and blur event

Tags: jquery

I am using both click and blur event. Find my code at http://jsfiddle.net/CyQ2w/11/

When using only click event: everything works fines. A click on a list populates value in text area.

When using both click and blur: A blur event takes priority and prevents click event to trigger.

Blur event is used only to hide div when textarea loses focus.

I have read about binding this two events to an element. But, in my case, elements [anchor and textarea] are different.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to implement an autocompleter input? Why not grab the one from jQuery UI since you already using jQuery?

Comment: Yes. jQuery UI did not suit our requirement. So I had to build my own.

Comment: Honestly (and this is not a shot at you personally) I very much doubt you can implement autocompleter as good as jQuery one in a reasonable time frame. It is likely MUCH easier to tweak it to suit your requirement instead.

Comment: That's true. But, we are done implementing it. Its just the above issue that is creating problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).bind("click",".username", function() {
      $("#message_board").val($("li.hovered div").text());
    return false;
});
```

this one should help. Also i recommend you migration to newest jquery and to use .on method instead of .bind